# why are stable distribution called stable?

Tags: stable-distribution

I know what a stable distribution is but I don’t know why do they call it Stable

I am not aware of anybody who is known by stable.

Is it possible because sum of a random variables end up with exactly the distribution of a single summand is a property associated with a stability?

Comment: The first line of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) directly answers your question.

Comment: @whuber it doesn’t it only defines it but it doesn’t say the intuitive idea behind the naming of stability

Comment: Permit me, then, to quote the portion of the article that I perceive to be an answer: "a distribution is said to be *stable* if a linear combination of two independent random variables with this distribution has the same distribution, up to location and scale parameters."  This is manifestly a form of closure of a scale-location distribution family under the process of forming linear combinations.  If it doesn't immediately remind you of the Central Limit Theorem, then studying the CLT would be the best place to begin establishing the intuition and motivation behind this idea.